# Regex for app version in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I am newer witn regex please someone help me

i want to make a regex to check version like `(1.1.1)` only allowed  please help me to make regex

Comment: i am really sorry but i am tring so many times but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\d+\.\d+\.\d+
```

will do it for you if the version only contain digits

```
2.1.1 :001 > s = "some string goes here 1.2.1 and 3.3.1"
 => "some string goes here 1.2.1 and 3.3.1" 
2.1.1 :002 > s.scan(/\d+\.\d+\.\d+/)
 => ["1.2.1", "3.3.1"] 
2.1.1 :003 >
```